# How to move bones and amature in edit mode altogether?

Tags: edit-mode

I need to move the armature and the bones that's in T pose to the center of the world.
But I can only grab the bones. How to move the mesh also altogether?

[image]

Comment: you're in Edit mode, you need to come back to Object mode

Answer (score 1):

Parent the mesh to the bones, and then move the bones in pose mode

Comment: Could you please add more to your answer to prevent it from being deleted? Thank you!